# Access Record Offset in Kafka Streams Aggregator

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple windowing topology:

```
builder.stream("input-topic", Consumed.with(...))
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(windowSize).advanceBy(windowAdvance).grace(windowGrace))
    .aggregate(Frame::new,
            this::windowAggregator,
            ...
    )
    .transformValues(FrameTransformer::new)
    .toStream()
    .selectKey((key, value) -> value...)
    .to("output-topic", Produced.with(...));
```

I'd like to put the actual record offset of the beginning of the window into the Frame aggregating object.

How can I get access to the record offset from the `windowAggregator` (`aggregate()` handler) function?

I know that I can get access to the record offset in the `FrameTransformer`, but that doesn't help me creating accurate `Frame` objects describing my windows in terms of start and end offset.

I've heard there's a way of doing that by inserting another `.transform()` call before the `groupByKey()`, there I can access the offsets, but then I'd need to modify the schema of my event records to store there the offset information inside.

Is there a (simpler) way of achieving my intention?

**Update**

In fact, I was able to get the accurate window start and end offsets in the `Frame` objects in the following way

```
builder.stream("input-topic", Consumed.with(...))
    .transformValues(EventTransformer::new)
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(windowSize).advanceBy(windowAdvance).grace(windowGrace))
    .aggregate(Frame::new,
            this::windowAggregator,
            ...
    )
    .toStream()
    .selectKey((key, value) -> value...)
    .to("output-topic", Produced.with(...));
```

But as mentioned above, at the expense of editing the schema of `Event` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get access to the record offset from the windowAggregator (aggregate() handler) function?

You can't. Your approach to use `transformValues()` before the aggregation (and to enrich the `Event` object is the right approach.

There was a proposal to extend the API to allow accessing record metadata within `aggregate()` and other DSL operators, but it was never pushed over the finish line (cf https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-159%3A+Introducing+Rich+functions+to+Streams).